# How to load JSON-Files module specific? Angular 4 - ngx-translate

Tags: angular, angular-translate, ng2-translate, ngx-translate

I am new to `Angular 4` and `ngx-translate`. I am looking for a way to load specific JSON-File for every module.

In my `app.module.ts` this code loads the json files for each language:

```
TranslateModule.forChild({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [Http]
  }
}),

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  console.log('aiaiaiaiaiaia');
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'src/app/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

However in another module this code:

```
TranslateModule.forChild({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [Http]
  }
}),

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  console.log('jojojojojojojo');
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'src/app/cca-campaign-module/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

This code doesn't gets executed ...

What is the reason why this is not working?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same behavior. In your app.module.ts, I believe it's recommended to using .forRoot(..) rather than forChild(..). Even with this change the child module specific translation JSON was not retrieved when loading the module. If you specify "isolated: true" as part of the child module, not app module, the translation JSON is retrieved, but not merged into the app module Translations because they are isolated to the module. This would require include common translations in both module translation JSON. Not sure if this is by design. I'll share any more finding as I encounte

Comment: this question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980408/use-ngx-translate-in-a-multi-module-angular-setup-and-child-libraries) and on the [github](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/592) but without an answer. I am actually facing the same issue and from what I understand `forChild` is only for Lazy loaded modules, not for modules already included in the main `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the file in Assets (parallel to app dir) directory

Note that if you would have generated with ng new YourAppname- this assets directory exists same line with 'app' directory, and services should be child directory of app directory. May look like as below:

```
::app/services/myservice.ts
getOrderSummary(): Observable<Address> {
    

    // get users from api
    return this.http.get('assets/ordersummary.json')//, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log("mock data" + response.json());
            return response.json();
        }
        )
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: I think you should provide a more complete answer and code as this does not help at all in solving the issue